# How do I get my android app to say "Task completed" after a task is completed?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm creating a user interface and want the device to say "Enjoy your meal" once it has reached the specified location (`onFinished`).

```
@Override
public void onFinished(PeanutPath runningPath) {
    log.d(TAG, "onFinished" + ", targetId：" + runningPath.getDestinationId());
    tvPilotStatus.setText("【Target：" + runningPath.getDestinationId() + "】" + "Finished");
    tts.speak("Enjoy your meal", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

I expect the device to say "Enjoy your meal" once it has finished its task.

Comment: What happens now? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues initializing `TextToSpeech` instance. You should be initializing it like this:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {
        int ttsLang = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "The Language is not supported!");
        } else {
            Log.i("TTS", "Language Supported.");
        }
        Log.i("TTS", "Initialization success.");
    }
});
```

This also helps you to check whether the language is available or not.